# python - web.py render html without using templates

Tags: python, web.py

```
import web

class index:
    def GET(self):
        i = web.input(age=None)
        return "You are " + i.age


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

This is my code. I'm testing something.

It isn't rendering the html. For example, If I return i.name by itself, and the age (i.age) parameter = `<b>25</b>`, it will show 5 as bolded and it renders it nicely. However, if I return `return "You are " + age`, the html will not render and it will just show as `Hi <b>25</b>`

Comment: how about `return "<body> You are " + i.age + "</body>"` ?

Comment: It works, but I'd like the html to be controlled by user input

Comment: like what? do you want the input to be of format `<tag>age</tag>` ?

Comment: yes, thats what i want.

Comment: in that case, the above solution should still work

Comment: Oh ok, it does work. Thank you. You can post your answer as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return "<html>Your are" + i.age + "</html>"` as any markup entered by the user would also be considered.